# How to sort this table by descending integer value?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table definition is like this:

```
create table test_1
( match_id varchar2(30), ts timestamp );
```

match_id is in format of integer.[A|B], such as 1.A, 1.B, 99.A or 99.B. rows with match_id on same integer is called a pair, so 1.A and 1.B is a pair while 99.A and 99.B is another pair. Database is Oracle 11.2 or higher.

```
SQL> insert into test_1 values ('1.A',current_timestamp);
SQL> insert into test_1 values ('1.B',current_timestamp-10);
SQL> insert into test_1 values ('100.A',current_timestamp-20);
SQL> insert into test_1 values ('100.B',current_timestamp-30);
SQL> insert into test_1 values ('99.A',current_timestamp-40);
SQL> insert into test_1 values ('99.B',current_timestamp-50);
```

I would like to select this table in descending order of the integer value in match_id column such as 100.B, 100.A, 99.B, 99.A, 1.B, 1.A but following statement returns 99.B, 99.A, 100.B, 100.A, 1.B, 1.A. Please suggest.

```
SQL> select * from test_1 order by match_id desc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
Select  * 
from test_1
order by TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(match_id, 1, LENGTH(match_id) - 2)) desc;
```

Here it is assumed that except last two characters, other character make a valid number.

Or using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

```
Select  * 
from test_1
order by TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(match_id,'^[0-9]+')) desc
```

This will takes only the digits from beginning

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler idea, if you have a bound for the length (number of characters) of the input strings, known to you without inspecting the data.

```
...order by lpad(match_id, 20, '0') desc    --  assuming all the strings are length <= 20
```

That is: treat everything as strings. Make them all the same length by adding zeros to the left, if needed. Then ordering them alphabetically (including the period and the letter A or B) is the same as ordering the numeric part and then also the A and B - all of them descending. (Note that ordering by the numeric part alone doesn't guarantee that B will come before A!)